# Why does my MVC website hang on startup when using Nimbus with Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azureservicebus, nimbus, masstransit

I have been using MassTransit in my application and I have decided to see how Nimbus differs.

I am trying to write a proof of concept system, using Azure Service Bus and Nimbus with Autofac.

So far I have successfully written a Console Application which is configured to use Nimbus using Azure Service Bus and Autofac. I have followed all the examples that I can find online, in particular the [PizzaSample](https://github.com/NimbusAPI/Nimbus/tree/master/src/Samples/PizzaSample) from the Nimbus Samples.

This console application successfully starts up, configures the Bus, connects to Azure Service Bus and creates me a new Queue as expected in my Azure Service Bus. The application then begins to publish "Heartbeat" events, which seem to show that this application works fine.

Next I move onto a simple off the shelf, Visual Studio Templated MVC Application with no authentication.
I have again added Autofac, Nimbus, and Nimbus.Autofac and configured as per the above PizzaSample Web application. When I start the application, as expected Global.asax.cs is invoked, which configures Autofac and configures my Bus. When the Autofac container is built, my Bus is AutoActivated and the Instance of my Bus is Started. I can also see in Azure Service Bus that a queue for my web application has also been created successfully. However, this is where my application now hangs.

Upon further debugging, I seem to be able to hit my default controller and action (Home/Index) and I can step completely through all the code in this controller right upto and passed my "return View()". So all appears normal. However the view is never rendered and the browser sits at "Loading" until I kill "IIS Express".

If I amend my Web Applications Nimbus configuration to take out the Instance.Start(), and run the application without starting the bus, the application runs fine as expected, but obviously without the bus being started so I can't send/publish any messages.

### Web Application Code

#### Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ContainerConfig.Configure();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        ContainerConfig.TearDown();
    }
}
```

#### ContainerConfig.cs

```
public static class ContainerConfig
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterModule<NimbusModule>();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        _container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(_container));
    }

    public static void TearDown()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### NimbusModule.cs

```
public class NimbusModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureServiceBus"].ConnectionString;

        // You'll want a logger. There's a ConsoleLogger and a NullLogger if you really don't care. You can roll your
        // own by implementing the ILogger interface if you want to hook it to an existing logging implementation.
        builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLogger>()
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .SingleInstance();

        var messageContactAssembly = typeof(MyTestEvent).Assembly;
        var handlerTypesProvider = new AssemblyScanningTypeProvider(messageContactAssembly);

        builder.RegisterNimbus(handlerTypesProvider);
        builder.Register(componentContext => new BusBuilder()
                             .Configure()
                             .WithConnectionString(connectionString)
                             .WithNames("Nimbus.Web", Environment.MachineName)
                             .WithTypesFrom(handlerTypesProvider)
                             .WithAutofacDefaults(componentContext)
                             .Build())
               .As<IBus>()
               .AutoActivate()
               .OnActivated(c => c.Instance.Start())
               .SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

#### MyTestEvent.cs (From an independent referenced contract assembly)

```
public class MyTestEvent : IBusEvent
{
    public MyTestEvent(Guid id)
    {
        Id= id;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}
```

#### HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    public HomeController(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _bus.Publish(new MyTestEvent(Guid.NewGuid()));

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

I obviously have some configuration wrong somewhere but I have spent hours looking at this and bashing my head against a wall. The closest that I can get to is thinking its something to do with the bus being started Async and perhaps somewhere the application is waiting for the Bus? But this is just a huge assumption and we all know assumptions are evil.

Has anyone seen this happen before and can offer any advice?

Comment: Are you using MassTransit v3 with Azure Service Bus?

Comment: No I'm currently using MassTransit v2

Comment: MT3 has native support for ASB, probably a much nicer experience that MT2 since ASB was never officially supported by MT2.

Comment: @jonhoare Did you ever get this working? I'm in a similar boat, I see that the WebApplication is running and it publishes events to the buz. I also created a test WebJob / CLI App and it subscribes to the events(i see the subscription in Azure). I see that on Azure the bus, the topic, the events are coming through, locally when i run my WebJob. But I don't see that the WebJob is actually picking up the messages and process them. What did you learn?

Comment: Same here... In a clean MVC website (c# 4.6.1) it works like a charm... but in a legacy project (also MVC c# 4.6.1), it doesn't send anything.

I've added code to start the bus and it gets stuck there